# Storing a list of unknown objects in an pojo

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

### What i want

I want to store a pojo with a list of objects as a json object into a collection. I do not know what objects are getting inserted into my pojo, thats why i need to keep it as generic as possible.

### My approach

Im using the reactive stream framework from mongo db.
The Pojo that should contains a list of objects

```java
public class Entity {

    public ObjectId id;
    public String type;
    public int version;

    public Set<Object> components;

    public Entity() { }
    public Entity(ObjectId id, String type, int version, Set<Object> components) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.version = version;
        this.components = components;
    }
}
```

The pojo that i created as some sort of test object.

```java
public class Chunk {

    public ObjectId id;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public Set<ObjectId> inChunk;

    public Chunk() { }

    public Chunk(int x, int y, Set<ObjectId> entities) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.inChunk= entities;
    }
}
```

My main

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        var pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().register(Object.class).automatic(true).build())
        );

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connString)
                .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
                .retryWrites(true)
        .build();

        // Receiving database and collection
        var mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        var database = mongoClient.getDatabase("Test");
        var collection = database.getCollection("Entity", Entity.class);

        // Create an entity to fill it with components and insert it
        var entity = new Entity(new ObjectId(), "player", 1, new LinkedHashSet<>());
        var chunk = new Chunk(1,2, new LinkedHashSet<>());
        entity.components.add(chunk);

        // Insert it
        var operationSubscriber = new SubscriberHelpers.OperationSubscriber<>();
        collection.insertOne(entity).subscribe(operationSubscriber);
        operationSubscriber.await();

        // Receive it
        var printDocument = new SubscriberHelpers.PrintSubscriber<>("YO : ");
        collection.find().subscribe(printDocument);
        printDocument.await();

        mongoClient.close();
    }
```

### The problem

The saved object is getting inserted, but its missing its object id. Furthermore, after loading, the entity.components is filled with one single object. But this object is just a raw "Object.class" from java and i cant cast that one to my saved "Chunk.class". So it somehow forgot its type upon loading and i cant acess it.

[image]
[image: In debugger, only loaded an object... not castable to previous saved chunk]

### My question

How do i save a list of "unknown" objects in my Entity.class and make sure that its getting loaded correctly with the type it was previously ?

Furthermore i would like to know if its then possible for subdocuments to reference other "Entity.class" aswell. Like having a "Chunk.class" inside Entity.components that references a few other "Entity.class" objects ( Note, not subdocuments ). And if thats the case, would they automaticly load ? Or do i need to implement that by myself ?

Im glad for any help, thanks !

Comment: You should be using a set of `Chunk` instances instead of a set of `Object`s for the property `components`.

Comment: @prasad_ Thats the problem, i have no clue what might get added to .components. I cant enforce a Set<Chunk> because a "Player.class" also might get added.

Comment: Then, you have to think about some generic class, or may be a Map collection (this allows storing filed names as Map keys and field values as Map values).

Comment: @prasad_ Alright thanks... do you know any resources on generic classes ? ^^ And what about inheritance ? Having a Set<BaseObject> instead, would that probably work or are there any downsides ?

Comment: BaseObject, Document, etc., is somewhat same as a Map. In this you can think about a field which identifies the type of object you are storing (Player, etc.).